# The player score increments by 9 instead of 1

Tags: java

So in this game i'm testing out, whenever the ball hits the paddle, I want the score to increase by 1. But instead it increases by 9 instead. How can I fix this? Here is the code. The 2nd method which is the update() method contains the score increase.

```
public class PlayState extends State {
    private Catcher catcher;
    private Ball ball;
    boolean visible  ;
    private int playerScore = 0;
    private Font scoreFont;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        catcher = new Catcher(400,425,80,25);
        ball= new Ball(200,0,40,40);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        visible=true;
        catcher.update();
        ball.update();
        if(ballCollides(catcher)){
            playerScore++;
            visible = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        //Draw Background
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GameMain.GAME_WIDTH, GameMain.GAME_HEIGHT);

        //Draw Ball(s)
        if(visible == true){
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(ball.getX(),ball.getY(),ball.getWidth(),ball.getHeight());
        }

        // Draw catcher
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(catcher.getX(), catcher.getY(), catcher.getWidth(),
                   catcher.getHeight());

        // Draw Score
        g.setFont(scoreFont); // Sets scoreFont as current font
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("" + playerScore, 350, 40); // Draws String using current font
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            catcher.moveRight();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            catcher.moveLeft();
        }
    }

    private boolean ballCollides(Catcher c) {
        return ball.getRect().intersects(c.getRect());
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyRelease(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT
            || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            catcher.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

2nd blck of code where the update method is being called

```
package com.jamescho.game.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.jamescho.framework.util.InputHandler;
import com.jamescho.game.state.LoadState;
import com.jamescho.game.state.State;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private int gameWidth;
    private int gameHeight;
    private Image gameImage;
private Thread gameThread;
private volatile boolean running;
private volatile State currentState;

private InputHandler inputHandler;

public Game(int gameWidth, int gameHeight) {
    this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
    this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gameWidth, gameHeight));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}

public void setCurrentState(State newState) {
    System.gc();
    newState.init();
    currentState = newState;
    inputHandler.setCurrentState(currentState);
}

@Override
public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    initInput();
    setCurrentState(new LoadState());
    initGame();
}

private void initGame() {
    running = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this, "Game Thread");
    gameThread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // These variables should sum up to 17 on every iteration
    long updateDurationMillis = 0; // Measures both update AND render
    long sleepDurationMillis = 0; // Measures sleep
    while (running) {
        long beforeUpdateRender = System.nanoTime();
        long deltaMillis = updateDurationMillis + sleepDurationMillis;

        updateAndRender(deltaMillis);

        updateDurationMillis = (System.nanoTime() - beforeUpdateRender) / 1000000L;
        sleepDurationMillis = Math.max(2, 17 - updateDurationMillis);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepDurationMillis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // End game immediately when running becomes false.
    System.exit(0);
}

private void updateAndRender(long deltaMillis) {
    currentState.update(deltaMillis / 1000f);
    prepareGameImage();
    currentState.render(gameImage.getGraphics());
    renderGameImage(getGraphics());
}

private void prepareGameImage() {
    if (gameImage == null) {
        gameImage = createImage(gameWidth, gameHeight);
    }
    Graphics g = gameImage.getGraphics();
    g.clearRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
}

public void exit() {
    running = false;
}

private void renderGameImage(Graphics g) {
    if (gameImage != null) {
        g.drawImage(gameImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
    g.dispose();
}

private void initInput() {
    inputHandler = new InputHandler();
    addKeyListener(inputHandler);
    addMouseListener(inputHandler);
}
```

}

Comment: You are probably calling update() continuously, which means that whenever ballCollides(catcher) returns true you increment playerScore. You'll need to find some kind of logic that makes sure this part of the code only gets called once.

Comment: Where are you calling update? Show the code.

Comment: @Zar I added it. I really wish I took notes earlier when reading.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if `ballCollides` may return true across multiple updates for a single collision.  I am not sure of this without looking at the code for the entire program, but based on what has been posted this would seem to be the most likely case.

One fix would be to keep track of the previous collision state for each catcher and ball combination (if there can be more than a single ball and catcher), and only update the score when the current state is colliding and the previous state was non-colliding.

E.g.

```
// Example using a single previousCollides state variable...
// Not suitable for a multi catcher / multi-ball game.
// The modifications break the contract this methods name seems to
// imply so the previousCollides logic should probably exist elsewhere
// and this code is only to illustrate the idea. 
private boolean ballCollides(Catcher c) {
    boolean collides = ball.getRect().intersects(c.getRect());
    boolean result = collides && !previousCollides;
    previousCollides = collides;
    return result;
}
```

The above is just an example, where to actually keep track of the previous collision data is up to you.  Maybe it should be kept within the catcher object itself as that would seem to make the most sense.

Comment: What I was doing was restting the position of the ball to the top of the screen whenever if collided with the catcher to save memory.